# Create a circle out of texts with CSS or CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/2usjbynf/)

I am willing to create a circle out of texts. So, I am having a list of anchor tags in a div. I created a circle using the basic properties but the anchor tag does not stay in it and tend to acquire the whole width of parent div.

What I can do is use: overflow:hidden to hide the overflowing parts from the circle but what I rather wish is to adjust the anchor tags properly inside the circle without cutting any portion of it.

Please suggest if any one has gone through such case with or without using javascript. Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/2usjbynf/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tag-cloud">
    <div class="tt">
        <a href="http://localhost/ameno/tag/8bit/" class="tag-link-66" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">8BIT</a>
        .................................................
        <a href="http://localhost/ameno/tag/wordpress-tv/" class="tag-link-174" title="2 topics" style="font-size: 10.709677419355pt;">wordpress.tv</a> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tag-cloud {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.tt {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;   
}

.tag-cloud a {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

What I have tried:

http://www.csstextwrap.com/

But that works only for a limited amount of text. And if I add some more text it is not good any more.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Something like https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Helpful article but what I am looking for is different. Please have a look at the edited post. you can see the image there.

Comment: You'll need javascript for that...which you would need to create the tag cloud anyway.

Comment: made edits to accept any suggestion using javascript too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing from your description you mean something like this: http://codepen.io/skeate/pen/YPyqWd

As talked about in this article: https://skeate.github.io/2015/07/13/Wrapping-Text-to-Fit-Shaped-Containers-with-CSS.html

It uses the:

```
shape-outside: polygon();
```

style to achieve it. The full css for it is:

```
@mixin circle($radius){
  width: $radius*2;
  height: $radius*2;
  border-radius: $radius;
  &::before{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: polygon(
      0 0,
      100% 0,
      60% 4%,
      40% 10%,
      20% 20%,
      10% 28.2%,
      5% 34.4%,
      0 50%,
      5% 65.6%,
      10% 71.8%,
      20% 80%,
      40% 90%,
      60% 96%,
      100% 100%,
      0% 100%
    );
  }
  > span::before{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    shape-outside: polygon(
      100% 0,
      0 0,
      40% 4%,
      60% 10%,
      80% 20%,
      90% 28.2%,
      95% 34.4%,
      100% 50%,
      95% 65.6%,
      90% 71.8%,
      80% 80%,
      60% 90%,
      40% 96%,
      0 100%,
      100% 100%
    );
  }
}

.circle{
  background: #accede;
  text-align: center;
  @include circle(5rem);
}
```

Or did you want text going in a circle like in GillesC's comment above.

Comment: If you put that code into the answer it would be great rather than linking the Codepen.

Comment: Thanks. That will help. Will give it a try right now and hope it will work on all browsers.

Comment: I didnt include all the code as there is a lot. Also I did not write the code myself which is why I linked. But i have added the css if you will find that useful,

Comment: Your solution worked great for me, but the shape outside property is not supported by safari and as suggested in the mentioned article, polyfill should be used. So did I. But even after setting polyfill there is no progress . So can you please give a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336621/polyfill-to-support-shapes-on-non-webkit-based-browsers